# 'Completing the square' in higher degrees

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

Let $p_2=ax^2+bxy+cy^2$, $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a \neq 0$;
$p_2$ is homogeneous of degree $2$.
By '[completing the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square) trick' we obtain: 
$p_2=a(x^2+\frac{b}{a}xy+\frac{c}{a}y^2)=
a(x^2+2x\frac{b}{2a}y+\frac{b^2}{4a^2}y^2-\frac{b^2}{4a^2}y^2+\frac{c}{a}y^2)=
a((x+\frac{b}{2a}y)^2+(\frac{c}{a}-\frac{b^2}{4a^2})y^2)=
a(x+\frac{b}{2a}y)^2+a\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a^2}y^2$

Now consider $p_3=ax^3+bx^2y+cxy^2+dy^3$, $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a \neq 0$; $p_3$ is homogeneous of degree $3$.
Similarly to the above trick we obtain:
$p_3=a(x^3+\frac{b}{a}x^2y+\frac{c}{a}xy^2+\frac{d}{a}y^3)=
a(x^3+3x^2\frac{b}{3a}y+3x(\frac{b}{3a}y)^2+(\frac{b}{3a}y)^3
-3x(\frac{b}{3a}y)^2+\frac{c}{a}xy^2-(\frac{b}{3a}y)^3+\frac{d}{a}y^3)=
a(x^3+3x^2\frac{b}{3a}y+3x(\frac{b}{3a}y)^2+(\frac{b}{3a}y)^3)+
a(-3x\frac{b^2}{9a^2}y^2+\frac{c}{a}xy^2-\frac{b^3}{27a^3}y^3+\frac{d}{a}y^3)=
a(x+\frac{b}{3a}y)^3+
a(\frac{c}{a}-3\frac{b^2}{9a^2})xy^2+a(\frac{d}{a}-\frac{b^3}{27a^3})y^3=
a(x+\frac{b}{3a}y)^3+
\frac{9ac-3b^2}{9a}xy^2+\frac{27a^2d-b^3}{27a^2}y^3=
a(x+\frac{b}{3a}y)^3+
\epsilon xy^2+\delta y^3$
where $\epsilon:=\frac{9ac-3b^2}{9a}=\frac{3ac-b^2}{3a}$ and $\delta:=\frac{27a^2d-b^3}{27a^2}$.

Now let $G: (x,y) \mapsto (x-\frac{b}{3a}y,y)$; $G$ is an (affine) automorphism of $\mathbb{R}$. We get that: $G(p_3)=G(a(x+\frac{b}{3a}y)^3+
\epsilon xy^2+\delta y^3)= aG(x+\frac{b}{3a}y)^3+
\epsilon G(xy^2)+\delta G(y^3)=ax^3+
\epsilon (x-\frac{b}{3a}y)y^2+\delta y^3=
ax^3+
\epsilon xy^2+ (\delta-\epsilon\frac{b}{3a})y^3$

Therefore, $\frac{\partial (G(p_3))}{\partial x}=3ax^2+\epsilon y^2$,
in which every monomial has even $x$ degree and even $y$ degree.

> Is there a similar trick for higher odd degrees $2n+1 \in \{5,7,\ldots\}$? Namely, can one find an affine automorphism $G$ of $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ such that every monomial in $\frac{\partial G(p_{2n+1})}{\partial x}$ has even $x$ degree and even $y$ degree. ?

The problem is that, for example, for degree $5$ the above trick only yields the existence of an automorphism $H$ such that:
$H(p_5)=Ax^5+Cx^3y^2+Dx^2y^3+Exy^4+Fy^5$, and then 
$\frac{\partial (Ax^5+Cx^3y^2+Dx^2y^3+Exy^4+Fy^5)}{\partial x}
= 5Ax^4+3Cx^2y^2+2Dxy^3+Ey^4$, which contains $2Dxy^3$.

Related questions are: [i](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2854468/an-affine-g-such-that-gp-x-mathbbr2-geq-0-p-in-mathbbrx-y-i) (former question of mine), [ii](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/4h2c1q/is_there_a_complete_the_cube_process_for_the_cubic/) (geometric interpretation) and [iii](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/940432/diagonalizing-xyz) (which is not exactly what I have asked; I did not ask for a sum of squares).

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think one rough way about thinking about it is that completing the square is doing an affine change of co-ordinates to get a desired form.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Please, do you think that it is hopeless to find such $G$ for degrees $ \geq 5$ (at least without making any further assumptions)? What if we allow $G$ to be any automorphism of $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$, not just an affine automorphism? In this case, $G(p_{2n+1})$ will not necessarily be homogeneous of degree $2n+1$, but we can still ask whether its partial derivative w.r.t. $x$ has monomials of even $x$ and $y$ degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By dehomogenizing the equation, this is equivalent to finding a substitution $x\mapsto x+c$ so that after substituting, $p(x)$ has no terms of even degree. This means that the even symmetric polynomials in the roots should evaluate to $0$ after translating all roots by $c$. This is not in general possible: $c$ is uniquely determined by the top two coefficients, and the set of $c$ which work for each individual lower degree coefficients is a Zariski-closed proper subset of $\Bbb R$, ie a finite collection of points. Since the polynomials are algebraically independent (by the fundamental theorem on symmetric polynomials), asking for $c$ to be in each of these subsets is a probability 0 condition.

Alternately, since the translation $x\mapsto x+c$ is a group action by $\Bbb R$ on the space of polynomials, it's enough to demonstrate that the orbit of $a_{2n+1}x^{2n+1}+a_{2n-1}x^{2n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$ is of small dimension. The dimension of the space of degree exactly $2n+1$ polnyomials is $2n+2$, and the dimension of the requested orbit is $n+3$ - for $n>1$, this gives that the requested orbit has smaller dimension than the whole space, and therefore a polynomial is in this orbit with probability 0.

Comment: Thank you. So in degree $3$ we just had 'luck', which we will probably not have in higher degrees? Also, what if we assume that all the coefficients of $p(2n+1)$ belong to $\{1,-1\}$ and still work over $\mathbb{R}$ (not over $\mathbb{Z}$)?

Comment: @user237522 In degree 3, the translation gets rid of the coefficient of $x^2$ and the derivative gets rid of the coefficient of $x^0$. For the restricted coefficient problem, you'd have to compute whether any of the given polynomials lie in the requested orbit. Probability 0 would suggest it's unlikely (although possible).

Comment: Thanks for the comment and for editing your answer.